# Dynamic Subdomains

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, dynamic, subdomain

On my new site I want to have dynamic subdomains. I'm trying to make it so that the subdomains use the same web root as the main domain, all under a single CodeIgniter installation. For example, subdomain.example.com would lead to example.com/subdomain, which is actually example.com/index.php/subdomain.

I've already the DNS, virtual hosts set up but I"m getting caught up on the [.htaccess](http://c0565262.cdn.cloudfiles.rackspacecloud.com/1299766529.txt).

The effect of the linked htaccess is that when navigating to any subdomain, it gets caught up in an infinite loop. ([Error log after one request.](http://pastebin.com/PgFH2ENF))  It's the same effect for www., which should just resolve to the main domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).\crashworks\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.crashworks.co/d/%1 [L,R=301]
```

The important things to notice here is the use of `(.*)` in the `RewriteCond` and the `%1` which is the backreference targeting the `RewriteCond` matches. Additionally the `!^www` prevents the infinite loop.

See the [apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for additional documentation on `mod_rewrite`.

I've also included a `/d/` as it may be easier to do your CodeIgniter routing with it, that is, having a specific controller and/or route setup.

**Side Note:** Also, consider using `www` with your site/domain setup, I've come to realize that it becomes much easier to write rules and generally other admin/server related config when dealing with multiple hosts of a single domain.

Unlike the above rules, I haven't tested the following rules which should work without the `www` (and you can keep the "enforce no www" rules):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^crashworks\.co [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).\crashworks\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://crashworks.co/d/%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: How will this interact with the existing rules?

Comment: it shouldn't have any negative interactions with existing rules except for the "Enforce NO www" rules, the rules above do depend on the main domain using a "www" ... see the second set of rules which should work with no "www"

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working..  Is it supposed to be an external redirect?  I'm going for the transparent look.